# Return value race condition in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, race-condition

In shell script using wget and getting its return value.
Example:

```
wget www.google.com   
if [ $? = 0 ]  
then  
  echo "success"  
else  
  echo "fail"  
fi
```

Linux running lots of shell scripts including one above. Suppose after executing `wget` in shell script, OS will give control to some other shell script and when again start executing above shell script, then `$`? return value will not be return value of `wget`.

Is there any way to avoid shell script return value race condition in linux?

Regards,
Sukhdeep Singh

Comment: Basically, you are talking something never happen. You don't need to worry about this. From man, $? Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

Comment: Even if there were a race condition, you could avoid it simply by using `wget` directly in the `if` statement: `if wget www.google.com; then ...`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no race condition here since every script is run in a different sub-shell and variables/environments inside a sub shell don't get overwritten by another running sub shell process.

Comment: But the fact that there is no race condition is still not a good reason to do `command; if [ $? = 0 ]; …`

Answer (score -1):

in shell comparasion, for if statement, you have two options:
integer and string :

```
for string you have to use :
if [ "$var" = "mystr" ];then 
 mycode
fi;
```

And for integer option, you have to use:

```
if [ 1 -eq $myvar ];then 
 mycode 
fi;
```

Notes :

```
 e = equvalent, l = less, g = great ,t = than
-eq ==
-le <=
-ge >=    
-gt >
-lt <
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the actual question.